# PIC 16F1503 - change the frequency of internal oscillator

Tags: pic, assembly

My configuration bits are as follows:

```
#include <P16F1503.inc> 
__CONFIG _CONFIG1, _FOSC_INTOSC & _WDTE_OFF & _PWRTE_ON & _MCLRE_OFF & _CP_OFF & _BOREN_OFF & _CLKOUTEN_OFF
__CONFIG _CONFIG2, _WRT_OFF & _STVREN_OFF & _LVP_OFF
```

The relevant part of code I am using for changing the frequency is this:

```
banksel OSCCON
movlw   b'01101000'     ; Int. osc. 4 MHz
movwf   OSCCON
btfss   OSCSTAT, HFIOFR ; Is internal oscillator running?
goto    $-1             ; No, loop one line back...
btfss   OSCSTAT, HFIOFS ; Is internal oscillator stable?
goto    $-1             ; No, loop one line back...
```

My debug tool is unfortunately just simulator. The problem is that execution never reaches the breakpoint on line 192:

[image]

So this means that internal oscillator never gets stable?

I am using:

- IDE:       **MPLAB X IDE v1.20**
- Compiler:  **MPASM v5.45**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Might be that the simulator doesn't simulate the HFIOFS bit. There are a couple of things it doesn't do.

Comment: Great.. That makes sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the simulator, you must comment out those two tests for the oscillator running or being stable. Since you don't have any hardware running, the tests will always fail. They should be OK if you use a debugger like the PICkit 2/3 or ICD 3.

Comment: So the configuration bits and code I posted seems ok?

Comment: It looks OK, I used something like it with the 16F1503.