# Only beta simulator and beta MPASM assembler for 16F1503

Tags: pic, assembly

My previous [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/33790/9354) makes me wonder whether it is even possible to develop with beta simulator and beta MPASM assembler support for 16F1503 (yellow dots):

[image]

If I can't expect workign end product, how can I write code in assembly for this particular MC? Can someone explain this? Why is MICROCHIP selling MCs, if there is no support for them? Those are questions arising in my had... Is there an explanation?

I am using the latest software:

- IDE:       **MPLAB X IDE v1.20**
- Compiler:  **MPASM v5.45**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the support for this part is only showing up as beta in MPLAB X, you should revert back to [MPLAB 8](http://www.microchip.com/Microchip.WWW.SecureSoftwareList/secsoftwaredownload.aspx?device=en019469&lang=en&ReturnURL=http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1406&dDocName=en019469&part=SW007002#) for primary development.

MPLAB 8 can be installed side-by-side with MPLAB X - you can even have overlapping projects on the same source files. In fact, this practice was recommended to me by Microchip when we received training on MPLAB X recently (make sure it works in 8 if there are doubts about X).

MPLAB X is a relatively new product for which legacy support will be improved over time (they focus on the newest parts first and work backwards).

Answer (score 2):

Don't use MPLAB X.  That is a total re-write and it will probably take a couple more years before it's really ready.  Get the latest version of MPLAB 8, and check back in a year or two.

Unless you are doing it for fun, you don't want to be a MPLAB X test pilot.  I do this for a living, so I'm sticking to MPLAB 8 until I absolutely have to update it.  Hopefully by that time lots of other test pilots will have already crashed and burned on my behalf and MPLAB X will be ready for real use when the job just needs to get done.

Comment: Yep, just when we thought we had all of the MPLAB 8 crashes and bugs understood, a whole new IDE is dumped on us ... in Java, no less...

Comment: @Madman: The old MPLAB has its warts, but on the whole its a pretty stable and useful piece of software.  There really aren't mysterious crashes and the like, at least not how I use it.

Comment: This seems like a really similar piece of advice!

Comment: I accepted @Madmanguruman's answer as he provided similar advice first...

Comment: @OlinLathrop No such luck here - random crashes and corrupted configuration bit displays for some of the PIC24 devices we're using. Plus X only has beta support for PICkit2 (don't get me started on PICkit3)

Comment: @Madman: Now it sounds like you're talking about MPLAB X.  I was talking about MPLAB 8 when I said we don't get mysterious crashes.

Comment: @OlinLathrop X hasn't been crashing much, although we haven't started using it full-time yet (just experiments).